# Error during scp transfer from windows to windows (ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient.put)

Tags: java, cygwin, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using package ch.ethz.ssh2 which has a class SCPClient to transfer files from one windows machine to another. The remote windiws machine has been installed with cygwin 2.874 (64bit) with the packages: openssl and openssh and other prerequisites.

Below is my java code for file transfer:

```
private void copyRecursively(File local, String remotePath) throws Exception {
    String name = local.getName();
    if (<iHaveSomeCondHereToExit>) {
        if (local.isDirectory()) {
            String newPath = remotePath + "/" + name;
            createRemoteDir(newPath);
            File[] files = local.listFiles();
            for (File f : files) {
                copyRecursively(f, newPath);
            }
        } else {
            
                String localPath = local.getPath();
                Log.info("copy file from " + localPath + " to "
                        + remotePath);
                osSupport.uploadFile(localPath, remotePath);
            
        }
    } 
}
```

I have a osSupport.java file which has uploadFile function as below:

```
public void uploadFile(String localFile, String targetPath)
            throws Exception {
        getScpClientObj().put(localFile, targetPath);
    }
```

I am getting error as

> java.io.IOException: Error during scp transfer
>
> at ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient.put(SCPClient.java:575) ~[ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar:na]

Please help me with this issue.
The same code works when i used the remote machine as linux server.

Comment: Is OpenSSH Server installed on the Windows Server? Otherwise you can just use Copy, Robocopy, or Xcopy from one Windows server to the other.

Comment: Both the machine has cygwin installed, hence openSSH installed on both

Comment: Cygwin will install an OpenSSH Client but did you also install the OpenSSH Server Daemon?

Comment: most probably not. any idea how to check it? did u mean to install on remote or host?

Comment: Can you connect with ssh to the server as user ? if not you need to proper configure the server with `/usr/bin/ssh-host-config`

Comment: I am able to connect to the server with ssh via putty